# I'd like to know who is online right now

Tags: discussion

I know this not a forum. And you can tell me to mind my own bussiness on this one. But I really like the ability to know who else is active at the moment.

It helps me decide if I should stick around for an answer, or if I should come back later.

What do you guys think?

Comment: (On a totally unrelated note, good job with all the editing -- it's encouraging seeing high-rep users worried about overall quality)

Comment: Hehe, same right back at ya... its awesome to ask a question and 10 minutes later find 'The Micheal' has removed all those horrible spelling mistakes and saved me from public embarrassment

Comment: Yeah, its really comfortable if you miss some mistakes if the English language is not your mother tongue. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I'm online! :)

There's a quite old [feature request on the main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/recently-active-users-list) about it, but you can post again there if you have a new argument to make about why it should be implemented. I generally think you should just post a question when you have it; I don't think you really need to target certain times to maximize exposure. During [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s peak usage times questions can be off the front page in 10 minutes, but here they can last for days. If we're lucky one day we'll have the same problem, but you probably don't need to worry about it now

Comment: +10 for being online :D... I'm not asking to maximize exposure. It would just be cool if, after asking my question, I can see that Gilles is active and my question would be answered shortly, or when no regulars are active I can go [climb](http://stefan.artspace44.com/climbing/) a bit and come back later

Comment: @Stefan Oh, I see; that's a pretty good argument for it

Comment: @Micheal, the climbing part?

Comment: @Stefan You should probably generalize it as "I want to know if I'm likely to get an answer soon or if I can do other things", but yes, the climbing part