# So why don't we get chat rooms?

Tags: discussion, chat

Not pushing for chat rooms, just inquisitive why Ubuntu SE gets to chat and we don't?

In a way, this will solve my [previous question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/id-like-to-know-who-is-online-right-now)

Answer (score 7):

<sub>(For the unaware, there is a "main" chat at http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/, although you need at least 20 reputation on the main meta to talk there.</sub>

We will get our own chat eventually, but the individual site chats are being rolled out in order of most active sites on the main chat, so as we have (as far as I know) no presence there at all, we're probably around the bottom of the list. If enough people are waiting for chat here I can look into getting us bumped up the list, but that's why Ubuntu got theirs before us: they use the main meta chat regularly. I haven't worried about it since the site-specific chats that do exist have been ghost towns so far

---

**Edit**: <s>I made a [room on the main meta](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/283/unix-and-linux?tab=general), so people can join that, but again being able to talk is unfortunately dependent on meta.SO reputation, not unix.SE. If you have at least 200 reputation here then associating an account there will get you 100, which is more than enough</s>

---

**Second Edit**: The centralized Stack Exchange chat is live now, so we have [a room there](http://chat.unix.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux). It's tied to your Unix profile (or whichever SE profile you want, you get to choose). I believe that will be our permanent place, the concept of per-site chats was abandoned

Comment: Are you aware of any reasons why they restrict the access to the rooms? There seems to be no open interface like IRC or Jabber or $foo, only this webpage?

Comment: @echox They're not "forbidden", just not included as part of the chat. The community is working on both [IRC](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59760/irc-access-for-the-chat) and [XMPP](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57316/offer-an-xmpp-method-for-chat) interfaces; I have no idea what their progress is though

Comment: Err I think I'm in a bit of a trouble. I created an account on SO first, and have no (1) reputation on meta (I think it's too mature everything I cared of has been answered). Now I can't join any chat rooms :(

Comment: @phu You can always reassociate an account later, but the SO devs are in the middle of moving some servers to New York, and currently meta is separated from the rest of the network (see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67128/cant-link-meta-stackoverflow-com-with-so)), so you won't be able to associate it anyway. For the moment I gave you explicit write access in the Unix and Linux room, so you should be able to talk there regardless of your reputation

Answer (score 1):

https://askubuntu.com/ (e.g. http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com) has [launched](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/7716/ubuntu) , we are still in beta. Ubuntu surpassed us in terms of popularity, so they got the chatroom first.